# Upload .app to iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I have developer account in apple. I make small app and want to send it to my friend. I make his iPhone to be developer. But I don't know when I send my .app to him how should he upload it. He hasn't got Mac.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send it by mail or ftp.
Don't forget to send the provisioning profile with it :)

He just have to drop the .app in Itunes. After that, he can check the application in the application list (under the iphone menu on itunes) and make a synchronisation.

To do that :

- Go to the device on itunes
- Click on app
- check the app in the list
- synchronize

You can also create an ipa (better than app)
check this [iOS Development Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW19), in the "Archiving Your Application for Testing" section. 
And then go to the website : [testflight](https://testflightapp.com/)
Your friend will be able to install the application only with the link in the email. No need for itunes.

Comment: Is this the only thing that he should do?

Comment: I edit my post, this is the way I send application to my client

Answer (score 1):

hi n_yanev whenever your sharing ipa file to any one those device udid's (device id provided by apple ) must be added to your provisioning profile while making of the ipa.After giving your ipa to any one there can be loaded directly from the itunes.There is no other option to load ipa to the device.

Comment: How can I compile my app to IPA file?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://testflightapp.com which makes this whole process a lot simpler.